# Facebook SDK 3.7 for Android request email permission

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using Facebook SDK for Android to allow users to register and use app. I want to get some basic info about user like user name and email. Anyway, I have problem because I get null pointer exception when trying to get user email.

```
String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();
```

I assuming that I get this error because I did not request for email permission. How I can do that?

Here is the **full code**:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

Button btnFacebook;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    btnFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook);


    btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "Prije sesije");
            // start Facebook Login
                        Session.openActiveSession(RegisterActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
                            // callback when session changes state
                            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                            @Override
                            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                                    Exception exception) {
                                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "U call");
                                if(session.isOpened()){                     

                                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "ako je sesija otvorena");

                                    // make request to the /me API
                                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCompleted");

                                            if(user != null){
                                                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "user razlicit od null");
                                                 String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ime "+user.getUsername().toString()+ "Email "+ email , 
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                String userId = user.getId();


                                                //new DownloadImageTask(ivProfile).execute("http://graph.facebook.com/"+userId+"/picture?type=large");



                                                Log.d("ID", userId);



                                            }
                                            Log.d("ID", user.getId());


                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "nije u sesisji");


                            }

                        });

        }
    });

}

 @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Get the permissions first**

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList(
        "email","user_location");
```

**The Method for getting the user information**

```
      Session.openActiveSession(RegisterActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            /*
             * Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(activity1,64206,
             * -1,activity1.getIntent());
             */

            if (session.isOpened()) {

                List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                            RegisterActivity.this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                    return;
                }
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("",""+user);  
                        try {

                            name=user.getName();
                            email=user.getProperty("email").toString();
                            location=(user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).executeAsync();

            }
        }
    });
```

**isSubsetof method**

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
        Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

put this code in **onActivityResult**

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d("Activity result","  "+requestCode+"   "+resultCode+"    "+data.toString());
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

Put **Internet** permission in Manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Declare **Facebook Login Activity** in manifest

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Comment: When I have added one more permission(birthday) as follows, its not working. Loading the RegisterActivity several times.

Comment: private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList(
        "email","user_location","birthday");

Comment: Hi, i'm facing the same problem. Your answer's great but facebook asks first for basic permissions, and IF i accept them, the popup open again and ask for mail permission. Any idea how can i have only one popup to ask permissions with mail ? thx :)

Comment: @Maxime no you cannot, with Facebook 3.0 during login you cannot request for more than public_profile permission which is provided by default.

Comment: This solution is perfect

Answer (score 0):

hey you can try this way...

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("id", "name", "picture","installed" )).setCallback(statusCallback));
```