# Android - Facebook SDK - Mail permission

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

i'd like to add mail permission to my App.

I've seen a lot of post but no one really match to my problem ...

- I do not use facebook loggin button
- I use the following code :

  ```
  Session.openActiveSession(InscriptionConnexionActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

  // callback when session changes state
  @Override
  public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

      if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

              // callback after Graph API response with user object
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                  if (user != null) {

                      System.out.println(user.getName() + " : connected");
                      register_facebook(session.getAccessToken());
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  } });
  ```

What do i need to do for having mail permission ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:-

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null) {
    session = new Session(this);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
}
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed())) {
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
      .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"))
      .setCallback(statusCallback));
}
```

see below link

[Facebook SDK 3.7 for Android request email permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077043/facebook-sdk-3-7-for-android-request-email-permission)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where do i have to put that code ?

Comment: @Maxime have u seen link once ?

Comment: please have a look to my new comment i'm really stuck :(