# App Crashes when i try to login into facebook android

Tags: android, facebook

I dont know why my app crashes throwing a NPE when i click the facebook login button. I have added and checked all the necessary library files. but still it crashes. kindly help me.

**My LogCat**

```
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.<init>(LocalBroadcastManager.java:110)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:102)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction(Session.java:1574)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.facebook.Session.setActiveSession(Session.java:971)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:1126)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:1035)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.trimex.amadora.FlipperRegister.intialiseFBLogin(FlipperRegister.java:398)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.trimex.amadora.FlipperRegister.onClick(FlipperRegister.java:292)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
05-29 13:28:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post `FlipperRegister.java`. The NPE arises from there

Comment: In FlipperRegister.java i just call the session and open it. the same code works fine with the previous version of my project.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the broadcast which when broadcasts, the receiver listens.

But what if the thing you want to respond to this broadcast is Null on the course as soon as it's broadcast.

So check your activity or fragment where you defined your listener if its instantiated before the call.

Comment: That listener belongs to Facebook SDK

Comment: What is line number 398 in `FlipperRegister.java` ?

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getStaticContext()).sendBroadcast(intent); this line throws error

Comment: Session.openActiveSession(this, true, Arrays.asList("email") dis is line no 398

Comment: you are using `this` in a `openActiveSession` as a parameter. Check if its null or not. Just before the line 398, use the condition like - if(this == null){ //DEBUG HERE } else { //Check HERE}. This will tell if its null as a first point. If its null, then the exception is because of this.

Comment: debugger passes the above line. the error is thrown in the session class of facebook.. in line `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getStaticContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);` in this line nothing is null but when try to call getinstance in quickviewer it throws NPE

Comment: No, the problem is in line 398 but the cause is `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getStaticContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);`. So this means that you are broadcasting for the active open session that has email as a permission but its null in session(line 398). Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077043/facebook-sdk-3-7-for-android-request-email-permission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54716/discussion-between-dinu-and-ved-prakash).