# Facebook Login Button with email responce

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I had implemented the facebook button following the facebook guide.It's working perfectly but

> first_name,
>
> last_name,
>
> email,
>
> sex,
>
> fb_id.

**I got all the things except email**.Might be I need to give some permission But I can't find it where to give it.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MainFragment mainFragment;
private LoginButton loginBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) 
        {
            if (user != null) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("first_name", user.getFirstName());
                i.putExtra("last_name", user.getLastName());
                //i.putExtra("email", user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                i.putExtra("sex", user.asMap().get("gender").toString());
                i.putExtra("fb_id", user.getId());

                Log.i("first_name", user.getFirstName());
                Log.i("last_name", user.getLastName());
                //Log.i("email", user.getProperty("email").toString());
                Log.i("sex", user.asMap().get("gender").toString());
                Log.i("fb_id", user.getId());

                finish();
                startActivity(i);

            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.i("TAG", "You are not logged");
            }
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) 
    {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    }
    else 
    {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}

public void goingToRegister(View v) 
{
    v.findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.image_click));

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
}

public void loginNow(View v) 
{
    v.findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.image_click));

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

**MainFragment.class**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity, container, false);


    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email","user_friends"));
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    return view;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
{
    if (state.isOpened()) 
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } 
    else if (state.isClosed()) 
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i("TAG", "responce: " + data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

In facebook I added the permission like this

[image]

Comment: You Should be able to find the settings under your App Details tab and select Configure App Center Permission and You need to type in email.

Comment: Then how to fetch the email.

Comment: You will be getting it with other fields check the output.

Comment: Trying to get it like this 

Log.i("email", user.getProperty("email").toString());

Comment: Try to dump the whole response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077043/facebook-sdk-3-7-for-android-request-email-permission/22089226#22089226

Comment: How to dump that @Muthu

Comment: Did you get the user.getProperty("email") in log? else you need to wait for a minute since changes take some time to reflect.

Comment: No it'd dtill giving error and check the image I attached is it the right way to add email?

Comment: Yes its the right way.

Comment: Try session.getPermissions() to list available permissions!

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPermissions() from the type Session

Answer (score 1):

The email field is not a standard one that is returned from the me endpoint, so you will need a specific Request to fetch it using the Request class.

Use this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/Request.java#L278

Set the fields on it that you want, like:

```
// Make sure the user is logged in first
Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), yourCallback);
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
// The fields you want in comma separated list
parameters.putString(fields, "id,name,email");
meRequest.setParameters(parameters);
meRequest.executeAsync();
```

You need the email permission before that works though.

You can use [the graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to see for the graph request should behave.

Answer (score -1):

Try this library, this is the simplest way to handle facebook https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook